# group by a calculated field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query like this

```
CASE 
              WHEN [col1] = 's' THEN '1'
              WHEN [col1] = 't' THEN '2' 
              WHEN [col1] = 'u' THEN '3' 
              WHEN [col2] = 'v' THEN '4'
.......
END AS product,
SUM(col3)
FROM dbo.TableA
```

I want group by on product?
How to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is use a subquery for your aliased `CASE` column.  With your query as a subquery, you are able to `group by` your aliased column.

```
select product
from
(
    select
    CASE  
        WHEN [col1] = 's' THEN '1' 
        WHEN [col1] = 't' THEN '2'  
        WHEN [col1] = 'u' THEN '3'  
        WHEN [col2] = 'v' THEN '4'
    END AS product, 
    SUM(col3) as Col3Sum
    FROM dbo.TableA 
) a
group by product
```

Comment: This works for SUM, but it would break for count(distinct col4).

Answer (score 6):

You will need to have the `CASE` in your `Group By` as well.  You cannot use the alias in a 
`GROUP BY`

```
SELECT yourColumn, otherColumn
   , CASE 
        WHEN [col1] = 's' THEN '1'
        WHEN [col1] = 't' THEN '2' 
        WHEN [col1] = 'u' THEN '3' 
        WHEN [col2] = 'v' THEN '4'
     END AS Product
   , anotherColumn 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN [col1] = 's' THEN '1'
            WHEN [col1] = 't' THEN '2' 
            WHEN [col1] = 'u' THEN '3' 
            WHEN [col2] = 'v' THEN '4'
         END
```

Comment: @AdamWenger I tried this solution, but it's run very slow for me.